# How to call AlertComponent in alert notificaion in my React JS code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, alert

```
const Services = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);


  const incNum = () => {
    setNum(num + 1);
  };

  const decNum = () => {
    if (num > 0) {
      setNum(num - 1)
    }
    else {
      alert(<AlertComponent/>);
      setNum(0);
    }
  }
```

As it is working like `alert("Congrats")`
why not is working `alert(<AlertComponent/>)`
How to do that please guide

Comment: So how to do that

Comment: alert is from mui?

Comment: Yes alertComponent is from mui

Answer (score 0):

Because `alert()` [has *nothing* to do with React](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert).

It is a browser utility, dating back to the earliest days of web browsers.
It doesn't display React components.  It doesn't display HTML.  It displays a string, and only a string.  `alert("Congrats")` works because `"Congrats"` is a string.

*Presumably* this `<AlertComponent/>` is something you want to display on your page.  In that case you would render it as part of your React code, as part of the `return` value for another component.

---

**Edit:** To elaborate a bit on how you would dynamically show a component...  Consider a state value like this:

```
const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false);
```

You'd use this in your render results to show or not show that component:

```
return (
  <>
    /* whatever else you're rendering, and... */
    { showAlert ? <AlertComponent/> : null }
  </>
);
```

So when the component renders, `<AlertComponent/>` will display only if that state value is `true`.

Then you'd update that state value whenever you want, for example:

```
const decNum = () => {
  if (num > 0) {
    setNum(num - 1)
  }
  else {
    setNum(0);
    setShowAlert(true);
  }
}
```

Maintaining/updating state and using that state to determine what to render is *absolutely fundamental* to React.  It's the foundation upon which *the entire framework* is designed.

Comment: So how to do it Sir?

Comment: @MuhammadHassan: How to do *what*, exactly?  How to display a component in your React code?  By including it in your render.  If you're not familiar with how to return JSX from a React component to render an element then you should *really* be starting with some introductory tutorials on React.  Because... that's how the UI is built at all.  If you haven't covered that then you don't have a UI yet, so clearly there's a next step in your tutorials that you need to get to.

Comment: Ignore my code I just want to return alert of mui styled component on "else" statement

Comment: @MuhammadHassan: *"Ignore my code"* - Ignoring your code is not going to help you fix your code.  *"I just want to return alert of mui styled component on "else" statement"* - To return the `<AlertComponent/>` you would, unsurprisingly, do this: `return <AlertComponent/>;`  ***However***, depending on how you *call* `decNum()`, this *probably* isn't going to do what you want it to do.  You need to return JSX *from your component*, not from click handler functions.  *No React tutorial* returns JSX from an even handler, because it doesn't make sense.  There's no reason for you to think it would.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan: I've updated the answer with a bit more of an example of how one might dynamically render an element in a component.